# Use jQuery to find the previous sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the HTML below, I would like to add a class to the first sibling P element that is before the div with the class "div-class".

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p> -> add class to this element
<div><p>test</p></div>
<div class="div-class"></div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
jQuery(".div-class").prev("p").addClass("p-class");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method only selects sibling element which is immediately before the element since you are using `p` selector it won't select anything because there isn't any `p` tag which is immediately before the element.

You can use [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) method to get all sibling elements which is before the element and [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first) method to get the nearest one among the collection.

```js
jQuery(".div-class").prevAll("p").first().addClass("p-class");
```

```css
.p-class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<div>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="div-class"></div>
This doesn't work:
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `siblings("p").last()`:

```
jQuery(".div-class").siblings("p").last().addClass("p-class");
```

```js
jQuery(".div-class").siblings("p").last().addClass("p-class");
```

```css
.p-class {
  color: #f00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<div><p>test</p></div>
<div class="div-class"></div>
```

jQuery's [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) returns all siblings from matched selector in order they are placed. So the desired sibling will be the `.last()` in the list.

Comment: FYI, positional selectors are [depricated](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
jQuery(".div-class").prev("div").prev("p").addClass("p-class");
```

```js
jQuery(".div-class").prev("div").prev("p").addClass("p-class");
```

```css
.p-class{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<div>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div class="div-class"></div>
```